# Building a visual scripting component (like Kismet)

Tags: visualization, kismet

I'd like to know how can one get started building a visual scripting component (or what is the more accurate term for this type of component?) such as UDK's and Unreal Engine's Kismet.

For those who are not familiar, the system allows connecting various pieces of logic visually, creating a possibly complex component out of smaller building blocks.

While the underlying data model may be (perhaps) something i can figure out for myself, it is the visual part that i am not sure of how to work out.

Are there any libraries that facilitate writing something like this? Where can i get started on thsi ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a gaming related question, it is more like general graphcis programming.

You need to implement some kind of GUI library yourself, and looks like you will need vector based graphics. You might want to use something like [OpenVG](http://www.khronos.org/openvg/) or similar for that.